# How to approach the modeling of paneling on walls and floors?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, workflow

Panelling in Sci-fi models is especially important because it adds visual interest and I would love to learn how to do it. I would like to learn how you model paneling, especially with complex shapes? I think I'm mostly confused about getting the fine lines between panels and how to conform them to the model especially on complex shapes.

Here are some references for what I want to do.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Bevel, Inset, Extrude, Edge split, Arrays, Deform... depends on the case... At it stands your question is too vague. Please try making it more specific...

Comment: If you know how to use the modeling tools, it shouldn't be too hard, if you have reference (like you do). just recreate it. If you don't know how to use the modeling tools there are a massive amount of tutorials. . . [like this one on sci-fi panel modeling](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/create-a-spaceship-corridor-part-1-of-2/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with the [***Array Modifier***](http://blender-manual-i18n.readthedocs.org/ja/latest/modifiers/generate/array.html) and a few modelling tricks.

First start by adding a defining shape for your panel, in this case it is a wall panel. Make sure that the edges join together properly:

[image: Base Shape]

Add an array modifier to see how it tiles and for reference when modelling in the next steps:

[image: Array]

Now start adding some details to this shape, beveling edges and doing basic extrusions:

[image: Third]

Now start modelling other pieces, like pipes, wiring, etc. and then join it to the mesh using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>:

[image: Fourth]

---

This is the basic technique, feel free to experiment and make it your own. Standard texturing and materials methods apply. I would very much recommend watching the [**BlenderGuru tutorial on making a space corridor**](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/create-a-spaceship-corridor-part-1-of-2/) as well.